# How to fix shrinking label?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

So, I have more than one label inside my uitableviewcell. I'm using autolayout for the ui. But I got some weird behaviour on one of my labels. Here is the video:

[image]

That one label that starts with "untuk" keep changing its size whenever I reload the tableview and I got below warning on the storyboard:

[image]

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: go to cell you created and set constraint 
Click+drag on datelable and drop on namelabel set equal width.try and let me know the result

Comment: @JRB I've tried that but I still got the same issue

Comment: solve your localization issue than you get proper result  OR  clear both lable constraint than clip them properly with cell

Comment: Show us your constraints for the Label. You need to make sure the UILabel has leading and trailing constraints to autosize correctly

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

this behavior may be because of dequeuing so in **cellForRow** reset label content before giving it new content

```
 cell.nameLabel.text = ""
```

Also put this before return cell

```
 cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Remove the date label leading constraint with the view as long as

```
picture->35->datalabel->10->nameLabel->10
```

with nameLabel lines property set to 0 to wrap

Comment: Can you share all constraints of the nameLabel , Also any more conflicts appear in console ??

Answer (score 0):

Check the `content compression resistance priority` of `size inspector` and set it to a higher value (maximum 1000).

Also, if you want to have fixed width or fixed line numbers, set those first.